# Ways to improve my code in terms of space and speed

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, dictionary

I have the following data structures that I want to save:

- X: a dict, keys are tuples of length 2 and values are natural numbers
- Y: a dict, keys are tuples of length 3 and values are natural numbers
- Z: is a list of lists, the values of the list are double
- W: is a dict of tuples, where the values are the list of natural numbers

  1. Generally, is it better (faster and space efficient) to use numpy array and operations or list operations? I didn't put any constraints on the type of the variables.
  2. What are the ways I can reduce the space of the saved file on the disk? I am saving them into gz file type.

Comment: Try looking at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `lists` are mutable and hence unhashable. Can't have a dict of lists.